# What are the disadvantages of enabling virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, emulator

I am developing apps for Android. The emulator recommends to enable virtualization.

But I'm not sure whether is it good for my computer in the long run? Also, my pc recommends me to disable virtualization.

Comment: Enabling virtualization won't affect your machine.

Comment: Where does your PC recommend you disable virtualization ?  By disabling it you are simply preventing the system at running at full potential.

Comment: Virtualization does not affect your physical machine, in fact it can give you many advantages when running emulators such as faster speed, 64bit, and the ability to use a program like VirtualBox (free) that can allow you to run blown Windows Installs in a VM so long as you have enough ram and storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Practically, its just enabling a 'special' part of your CPU *specially* designed to speed up virtualisation. Essentially it allows a VM to access specific instructions and talk to memory a little more directly and results in significantly improved performance.

You don't need it if you're not running a VM (so lots of users don't need it). There's a few *theoretical* exploits like [blue pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_(software)) but nothing in the wild.

Many systems come with virtualization extensions turned on by default and there's no issues with them.